# Running an ECS Task on a Schedule With .NET

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-ecs

I am currently using the IAmazonECS.RunTaskAsync API to run a task on ECS immediately. Now, I would like to postpone it to some point in the future. According to the documentation, it should be possible, but I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: Could you quote the documentation and provide the link?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html

Comment: @RicardoPeres can you share your code for starting an ECS task please, I can't find any examples online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CloudWatchEvents from Amazon.CloudWatchEvents namespace for that.

```
var putRuleRequest = new PutRuleRequest
{
   Name = "test",
   RoleArn = "IAM_ROLE_ARN",
   ScheduleExpression = "rate(5 minutes)",
   State = RuleState.ENABLED,
};

var putRuleResponse = client.PutRuleAsync(putRuleRequest).Result;

var putTargets = new PutTargetsRequest()
{
   Rule = putRuleResponse.RuleArn,
   Targets =
   {
       new Target
       {
           Arn = "cluster arn",
           RoleArn = "ecs events role",
           EcsParameters = new EcsParameters
           {
               TaskDefinitionArn = "arn for the task definition",
               TaskCount = 1
           }
       }
   }       
};

var response = await client.PutTargetsAsync(putTargets);
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

Comment: What about passing parameters to the task definition (environment args) like we do with RunTaskRequest.Overrides ?

Comment: Also, what Arn should I pass in the Target instance?