# Running a Task with CloudWatch Events with Environment Parameters

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I know how to schedule a task to be run in the future with a solution like the one described in [Running an ECS Task on a Schedule With .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50409411/running-an-ecs-task-on-a-schedule-with-net). The actual task is a Docker image and I would like to pass it some arguments using the environment variables. Is this possible at all? If not, how can I pass arbitrary parameters to a scheduled CloudWatch Event that can be picked up by a .NET Core application running in ECS?

Comment: Is there any way at all to pass any parameter to a CloudWatch Event scheduled task?